# Correspondence between map of sheaves and a global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme (I don't think any other conditions are needed on $X$) and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$. I've read somewhere that the map of sheaves $$\varphi:\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{L}$$ corresponds to a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$. Is this a basic fact about invertible sheaves, or sheaves in general? How is this correspondence constructed?

Also, since $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle, then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism if and only if $s$ is nowhere vanishing. Why is this true?

Any references (particularly in Hartshorne) would be appreciated, I'm trying to understand the invertible sheaves better.

Comment: **Hint**: locally $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial!

Comment: This is a basic fact about sheaves of $O_X$-modules in general. It is entirely analogous to the fact that $R$ is the free $R$-module on 1 generator.

Comment: @ZhenLin The thing I realised is that I don't know much about a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$! I know sometimes $s$ is always trivial, for example when $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{O}(-n)$ for some integer $n$ and a suitable $X$. For the map $\varphi$, I know that for a covering $\{U\}$ of $X$, we have $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \cong \mathcal{L}(U)$. Do we get the corresponding global section by gluing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the morphism $O_X \rightarrow L$ that sends $a \in O_X(U)$ to $a s|_U \in L(U)$. This is a morphism of $O_X$-modules as if $V \subseteq U$, then $(a s|_U)|_V = a|_V s|_V$. Note that $1 \in O_X(X)$ is sent to $s$

Conversely, given a morphism $f : O_X \rightarrow L$, let $s = f(1) \in L(X)$. Then, for open sets $U \subseteq X$ and $a \in O_X(U)$, $f(a) = a * f(1|_U) = a s|_U$.

These two constructions are inverses. Note that I never used that $L$ is invertible, so this holds for any sheaf of modules on any ringed space.